# python shutil.rmtree throwing errors

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone explain to me why shutil.rmtree is throwning errors saying directory is not empty?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "W:\__init__.py", line 90, in makePatch
    myprog.copy_data()
  File "W:\myprog.py", line 143, in copy_data
    self.cleanupTempDir()
  File "W:\myprog.py", line 138, in cleanupTempDir
    shutil.rmtree(self.TEMP_DIR)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 256, in rmtree
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 254, in rmtree
    os.rmdir(path)
WindowsError: [Error 145] The directory is not empty: u'e:\\PatchData\\Data'
```

Comment: Perhaps there is some external process that keeps adding new files to that directory?

Comment: nope, no external processes are writing to that location.

Comment: Maybe there's a hidden file. Try `for x in os.walk(u'e:\\PatchData\\Data'): print x`. If you get more than one item printed, you've still got files.

Comment: So there are no hidden files on the source that this was copied from. Also there are files left there because they were not removed by shutil.rmtree.

Comment: What kind of files were left? Were all the files left untouched? Does it occur only for a specific directory within that tree (if you move that directory elsewhere, does the call succeed)?

Comment: All files are left untouched. Seems to be all directories. I have not tested specifying any other directories, but I do get this error on all 15 directories that I copy files to. I just reviewed my last run and it looks like I am no longer getting the error. I guess the files were being marked as read-only (I had to add a line specifically to clear the read-only flag after copying as it keeps getting set for some unknown reason). Funny though the last time I tried to remove a read-only file I got an error that said what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the files were being marked as read-only. After adding a line to remove the read-only flag after the files are copied I am no longer getting this error. Strange that it would look like it is not even trying to remove the files or at least not raising any exceptions on the files only the directories.

Comment: Hi Thexder, What line did you add to remove the read-only flag? I am getting same error for a temporary folder assigned to a specific user.

Comment: Hi can you please provide a little more detail. where and how to add the line. Should it be in shutil.py

Comment: Perhaps the line added is os.chmod()? From the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.chmod):

"Although Windows supports chmod(), you can only set the file’s read-only flag with it (via the stat.S_IWRITE and stat.S_IREAD constants or a corresponding integer value). All other bits are ignored."

Answer (score 4):

**Linux**: I had encountered this error as well while handling a temporary folder: I had a `os.makedirs` call within a `__init__` constructor and a `shutil.rmtree` call within a `__del__` deconstructor, the code made use of the `multiprocessing` library; the folder was constructed sequentially but destroyed whenever the process terminated is execution. As such the error was not always reproducible, but it occurred, supposedly, only when two processes tried to destroy the folder at the same time, and without a proper locking mechanism, those errors were thrown. It happened because for some unknown reason the `__del__` deconstructor was called more than once.

The errors were like:

```
Exception ignored in: <function VideoMaker.__del__ at 0x7f6066a888b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VideoMaker.py", line 49, in __del__
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/Marco/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 670, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/Marco/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 717, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
    shutil.rmtree(self.temp_videoclip_dir)    
  File "/home/Marco/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 672, in _rmtree_safe_fd
  File "/home/Marco/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 715, in rmtree
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/Marco/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 670, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '12.mp4'
```

Or

```
OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: 'tmp/tmp.videoclips/'
```

---

### Do not use `rmtree` in a `__del__` deconstructor:

An object deconstructor may not always have a predictable behaviour, as such refrain of using OS' IO operations inside. Create a separate function instead and call it at the end of the object scope.

### If using multiprocessing or threading : `LOCK`

Docs:

- [***multiprocessing.Lock***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=lock#multiprocessing.Lock)
- [***threading.Lock***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=lock#threading.Lock)

Docs Example: *[Synchronization between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes)*

```
l.acquire()
try:
    if os.path.isdir(path_to_delete):
        shutil.rmtree(path_to_delete)
finally:
    l.release()
```

---

### If there is really no other way:

```
def try_to_rmtree(can_still_retry):
    if can_still_retry:
        try:
            if os.path.isdir(path_to_delete):
                shutil.rmtree(path_to_delete)
        except:
            try_to_rmtree(can_still_retry -1)

can_still_retry = 5
try_to_rmtree(can_still_retry)
```