# Python selenium webdriver for firefox not opening consistantly

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am using the following python script to open and start Firefox browser. It works at times while in other cases,it is giving an error.What am i doing wrong here?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

The error i am getting is this which is not happening always.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "seleniumtest.py", line 4, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.53.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdrier\firefox\webdriver.py", line 103, in __init__
self.binary, timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.53.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdrier\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 49, in __init__
self.profile.add_extension()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.53.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdrier\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 91, in add_extension
self._install_extension(extension)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.53.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdrier\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 287, in _install_extension
shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 256, in rmtree
onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 254, in rmtree
os.rmdir(path)

WindowsError: [Error 145] The directory is not empty: 'c:\\users\\cgdc\\appata\\local\\temp\\tmpqirkg6.webdriver.xpi\\components'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your file is having only read-only flag.

refer :-

[python shutil.rmtree throwing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109244/python-shutil-rmtree-throwing-errors)

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: can u please provide more clarity on what is to be done so that i can try and accept the answer if correct.